# Transforming programmed data application into Core data application

Tags: iphone, core-data, queue

i read a lot about Core Data in the apple developer section and here on stack overflow and i wanted to ask several questions before i start trying to implement them into my application that at this time works only with programmed data.

Idea for application is : user is a racer. He drives on different circuits. Each circuit has several named curves that are driven through in a certain speed and with certain efficiency. 
So the application has to store Circuits, a number of Curves for each circuit and many (like 200) drivethroughs through individual Curves storing the top speed and efficiency (for example string "Outstanding" "Good" "Bad"). The drivethroughs are used in the app in a queue, where last in means first out once you reach say 200 drivethroughs to allow improvement in statistical data over time and experience of the driver.

I have created the Entities with appropriate Parameters and Relationships.

Now for the starter, i would like to define a sample circuit, which is created on first launch of the application and that is loaded then with user changed or inputed data later on.

1 - i guess since the amount of data isn't large i could generate the data on first run, store it into core data and then at each start of the application somehow check whether the core data are there or not and based on that either create new or use current. I read about storing data into plist and importing them via xml and stuff, but i don't need to do this right? I can create, save, and then check if some data is present to know whether this is first app start or isn't?

2 - i am not exactly sure how to save a queue to core data. At the moment i designed it in my head so, that the Queue for each Curve will be made of Drivethrough entities with many to one relationship to curves with a parameter called index, so that i know which drive through was first and which last. I am not sure then how will i implement the queue abilities of removing the first drive through. Will i be forced to load all data, process it in the queue and then save all data to core data? Or will it accept some sort of remove first drive through and recount the indexes?

3 - am i right to say, that all my data loading should be made in my view controllers in "viewWillAppear"? And save them instantly after user presses the Save or Input button for each drive through?

I am not asking for code i just would love someone to tell me if this is generally a good approach or if you would do it diametrically different.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Storing data in an external plist file then importing to a `NSDictionary` via `+dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:` then iterating through this dictionary and importing into your Core Data store is not necessary in this case.  It would be necessary if you wanted to serialize your circuit data externally so a user could import circuits or so you could change the initial circuit by hand by editing the XML data in the plist.

**2)** Pre iOS-5.0, entities are stored in Core Data as an unordered `NSSet`.  If you are targeting iOS 4.x, you will need to add an attribute to store the order in the queue, which will let you calculate which item was added last.  You'll also have to write a method to search the entities and return the highest numbered sort attribute, so you know what to use for the next drivethrough sort attribute.  If you are targeting iOS 5.0 only, you can mark the relationship as ordered which will store it as an `NSOrderedSet`.  See: [Core Data Release Notes for iOS 5.0 - Managed Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#releasenotes/DataManagement/RN-CoreData/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010637-CH1-DontLinkElementID_4)

**3)** Running the data loading code in `-viewWillAppear:` depends on how long it takes to generate or load the data. If it takes a noticeable amount of time, you won't want to do this synchronously as it will block the main thread UIKit runs on if the code is running in `-viewWillAppear:`  If the time isn't trivial (under 100-200ms at least), you will want to generate the data in a background thread which can be kicked off in `-viewWillAppear:`.  The easiest way to accomplish this is using a [Dispatch Queue](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW21) and [`dispatch_async()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008079-CH2-SW7)

Comment: Did you mean -viewDidAppear: for the background thread? Or did you mean really -viewWillAppear: and therefore i dont understand it?

Comment: If you load the data in `-viewDidAppear:` and show an activity or progress indicator view, then this is a non-issue.  But my concern was that if the loading process takes too long, `-viewWillAppear:` wouldn't return until the loading code was done (unless run in a background thread).